# using a custom view for overflow menu items

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm having real difficulty doing anything to the overflow menu in actionbar sherlock.

[image: screenshot]

Ideally, I would like to use a custom `TextView` for each item in order to set a different font on it and change the colour of the `pressed` state.

I have tried (all without success):

[Changing The Style Of Actionbar Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14193071/changing-the-style-of-actionbar-overflow)
[Actionbar styled overflow menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859794/actionbar-styled-overflow-menu-items)
[listview as action overflow in sherlock actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119237/listview-as-action-overflow-in-sherlock-actionbar)
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/actionbarsherlock/5lHOKNlXn_4/f9XicMXbFFAJ

My app will have different fragments, all extending `BaseFragment` with different items in the overflow menu. I'm also using the v4 support package. I'm creating my menu like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_borrow, menu);
}
```

activity_borrow.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_filter"
        android:title="test"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
/>
</menu>
```

My app uses a theme that inherits from `Theme.Sherlock`.

How can I used a custom view inside that menu? Or at the very least, how can I change the default blue `pressed` state?

Comment: try this http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/ generate ur own style and use it

Comment: I don't want to overwrite the styles for my whole app - i just need one small section which that generator doesn't provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the colors of the overflow list items, add two items to your application theme which is usually defined in `res/values/styles.xml`:

```
<item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView</item>
<item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView</item>
```

In that same file, add the style that you have just assigned:

```
<style name="DropDownListView" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ListView.DropDown">
  <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background</item>
</style>
```

And finally create a selector drawable `selectable_background.xml` in the drawable folder, containing this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" >
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/focussed_color" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/pressed_color" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Finally, define the colors which are usually placed in `colors.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <color name="pressed_color">#FF8E4067</color> <!-- your purple tone already ;) -->
    <color name="focussed_color">#DD8E4067</color>
</resources>
```

In my app, I used the "ActionBar Style Generator" as baboo suggested, which handles everything for you conveniently. For this answer, I just extracted and simplified the parts that I think make up the overflow menu styling.

I think there is some mystery about the effects of styling three different items:

- From my understanding, `android:dropDownListViewStyle` includes the
  overflow menu that hides behind the "three dots" in the ActionBar.
- ***Not to be confused with*** `android:actionDropDownStyle`, which is used to the style the app navigation dropdown in case you used `actionBar.setNavigationMode(NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST)`
- However, some Android devices with a hardware menu button (e.g. the Nexus S or Galaxy S3 Mini)
  don't display the "three dots" but an overlay menu that slides in from
  the bottom of the screen if the hardware menu button is clicked. `android:popupMenuStyle` is the correct attribute to style this.

Again, this is only as far as I can remember from my own app development.

Also, make sure to check that no other style files (e.g. folders with [configuration qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)) overwrite the styles that you have just defined.

All in all, I understand that this would only change the background color of the list items. To use a completely custom view in there, you might create a [custom spinner view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14123377/1140682), add a dummy button with a "three dots" icon to your ActionBar and open the spinner on click.